# How to update a date field automatically every month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a date field in a table that needs automatically moved on to the next month after the previous date has passed and needs to account for differing lengths of months and also when the year changes e.g if the field had the following dates.

```
02/01/2019 would need moved onto 02/02/2019
28/02/2019 would need moved onto 28/03/2019
29/06/2019 would need moved onto 29/07/2019
28/12/2019 would need moved onto 28/01/2020
```

The reason this needs to be automated is that we can have thousands of clients where this date field needs changed and would be impossible to carry out manually.

Can this be done and if so how?

Comment: What happens to 31st January, since February has no 31st day?

Comment: Hint:  `+ interval '1 month'`.

Comment: Hi To simplify this we have decided to only have dates input up to the 28th of a month removing the issue for february and dates that would have 31st moving onto a month that only has 30 days

Comment: SQL tag on this website is meant to indicate SQL as laugauge (ANSI/ISO SQL standard) not a RDMS..  Based on your tags i would say you need to use a cronjob and use @GordonLinoff suggestion to update.

Comment: This is a SQL server database and i thought there would be a way to write a SQL script and perhaps run as a job via SQL Server Agent but as i am not an expert thats why i posted here for help

Answer (score 0):

Hope the code will be of help. The comment of @GordonLinoff was the solution.
The code was produced from Microsoft Server.

```
SELECT Your_Column, ' would need moved onto ' AS Your_Message_Column, DATEADD(month, 1, Your_Column) AS UpdatedDate_Column
FROM Test_Db.dbo.Sheet1$
```

Find attached an example of the input and output.

```
2019-01-02 00:00:00.000  would need moved onto  2019-02-02 00:00:00.000
2019-02-28 00:00:00.000  would need moved onto  2019-03-28 00:00:00.000
2019-06-29 00:00:00.000  would need moved onto  2019-07-29 00:00:00.000
2019-12-28 00:00:00.000  would need moved onto  2020-01-28 00:00:00.000
2019-01-31 00:00:00.000  would need moved onto  2019-02-28 00:00:00.000
2019-03-31 00:00:00.000  would need moved onto  2019-04-30 00:00:00.000
```

For the problem of repeating the query, there is the possibility of comparing the dates as you mentioned in the comments. It should be noted that equation would leave out the later dates.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Your_Column = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 120) THEN DATEADD(month, 1, Your_Column)
    ELSE Your_Column
    END
FROM Test_Db.dbo.Sheet1$
```

Comment: Thanks for your input JoPapou but the 'would need moved to' was only to indicate that i wanted the previous date in the field updated to the next month. So where the current date was 02/01/2019 then the new date in the same field should become 02/02/2019.

Comment: . i have the following code UPDATE mytablename SET dateinfield = DATEADD(month, 1, Date in Field). However if i run this daily using SQL Agent Job it would move every date in every field forward by 1 month everytime it ran so i need a way to only move the dates forward once per month.

I thought of adding WHERE  GETDATE() = Date in Field so this would only move the date forward when the date in the field equaled the GET DATE. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hi JoPapou Thanks for your input on this but i have it working using Update table
set mydatefield = DATEADD(month, 1, mydatefield)
where cast(mydatefield as date) = cast(GETDATE() as date)